# HTML numbering equations in the right margin

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Title</title>
    
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css_and_scripts/style.css">
    <!-- Support for math ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML"></script> <!--|-->
    <script type="text/x-mathjax-config">                                                                                         <!--|-->
        MathJax.Hub.Config({                                                                                                      <!--|-->
            tex2jax: {                                                                                                            <!--|-->
              inlineMath: [ ['$','$'], ["\\(","\\)"] ],                                                                           <!--|-->
              processEscapes: true                                                                                                <!--|-->
            }                                                                                                                     <!--|-->
        });                                                                                                                       <!--|-->
    </script>
    <!--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-->
</head>

<body>
        <p>Some text and in the middle I want an equation:
            <equation id="my first equation" style="">$$\intop_0^1f(x)dx=\pi\text{.}$$</equation><div class="equation_number">(1)</div>
        and now the text continues</p>  
</body>

</html>
```

with this CSS:

```css
.equation_number {
    text-align: right;
}
equation {
    display: block;
    border-style: dotted;
    width: 90%;
}
```

which produces this (the dashed box is just for debugging purposes):

[image]

and I want to show the (1) aligned with the equation as in this example:

[image]

I have been struggling with this for a while now and I have ran out of ideas. I am just starting with HTML and CSS. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest using `display: table;` to gain more control over the width while preserving alignment.

```css
.equation {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

.equation__content,
.equation__number {
  display: table-cell;
}

.equation__content {
  width: 90%;
}

.equation__number {
    text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-mml-chtml.js"></script>
<script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js"></script>
<p>
  Some text and in the middle I want an equation:
  
  <div class="equation">
    <equation class="equation__content">$$\intop_0^1f(x)dx=\pi\text{.}$$</equation>
    <div class="equation__number">(1)</div>
  </div>
  
  and now the text continues
</p>
```

Answer (score -1):

The `<equation />` and `<div class="equation_number" />` tags need to be wrapped in a flex container. Flexbox is a layout feature of CSS that aligns content within a container. Read more about it [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

```
<div class="center">
    <equation id="my first equation" style="">$$\intop_0^1f(x)dx=\pi\text{.}$$</equation>
    <div class="equation_number">(1)</div>
</div>
```

Then add the following css for the "center" class, which makes the container a flex container and aligns the items in it vertically:

```
.center {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
```

Also, you should not put a `<div />` inside `<p />` tags. Close the first paragraph tag and then add an opening paragraph tag to the one under the div in-between.